# How do add a column in a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have imported data from a file into a data frame in R. It is something like this.

```
Name      Count   Category
A         100     Cat1
C         10      Cat2
D         40      Cat1 
E         30      Cat3
H         3       Cat3
Z         20      Cat2
M         50      Cat10
```

So now i want to add the **Category** column depending on the values in the column **Name**. So something like if Name = (A, D), Category = 'Cat1' etc.

This is only a simple example I am giving. I have a large number of Names and Categories so I want a compact syntax. How can I do this?

Edit: I've changed the example to better suit my needs as the name can be anything not numeric. Sorry for not being too clear before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a map. (UPDATED to use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`)

```
df <- data.frame( Name = c('A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'H', 'Z', 'M'), 
                  Count = c(100,10,40,30,3,20,50), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Categories <- list(Cat1 = c('A','D'), 
                   Cat2 = c('C','Z'), 
                   Cat3 = c('E','H'), 
                   Cat10 = 'M')
nams <- names( Categories )
nums <- sapply(Categories, length)
CatMap <- unlist( Map( rep, nams, nums ) )
names(CatMap) <- unlist( Categories )

df <- transform( df, Category = CatMap[ Name ])
```

Comment: +1 Nice use of `Map()`. This is the second time in a week someone here has used `Map()` in an answer and they seem very useful indeed.

Comment: @pchalasani Thanks this is a nice way to do the recoding. However I tried this and the mapping is all wrong somehow when I did it in my actual data. The example you give works just fine. Any possible reasons for this?

Comment: @sfactor that is hard to say unless I see more of your actual data

Comment: @pchalasani I've added what I've done in the question. What am I doing wring here?

Comment: @sfactor: got it! You can fix it if you use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the first line when you are constructing the data frame. I fixed my solution to do this. Incidentally, R's default behavior of treating string-valued data-frame columns as Factors often bites me. I have to keep saying `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in many places in my code. Sometimes I just set it to FALSE globally as in `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` because I rarely need to interpret strings as factors in my work, but your use may be different.

Comment: Without `Reduce`, `Map` seems odd... why not just use `mapply`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ifelse`. If your data frame were called `df` you would do:

```
df$cat <- ifelse(df$name<100, "Ones", "Hundreds")
df$cat <- ifelse(df$name<1000, df$cat, "Thousands")
```

Comment: sorry I should have been more clear, so I changed the example, the name can be any alphabetical value not numeric. but thanks i'll try to apply a logic like this and see.

Answer (score 2):

[Update following the OP's comment and altered Q]

```
DF <- data.frame(Name = c("A","C","D","E","H","Z","M"),
                 Count = c(100,10,40,30,3,20,50), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
lookup <- data.frame(Name = c("A","C","D","E","H","Z","M"),
                     Category = paste("Cat", c(1,2,1,3,3,2,10), sep = ""),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Using the above data frames, we can do a data base merge. You need to set-up `lookup` for the `Name` `Category` combinations you want, which is OK if there aren't a very large number of `Name`s (At least you only need to list them once each in `lookup` and you don't have to do it in order - list all `Cat1` `Name`s first, etc):

```
> merge(DF, lookup, by = "Name")
  Name Count Category
1    A   100     Cat1
2    C    10     Cat2
3    D    40     Cat1
4    E    30     Cat3
5    H     3     Cat3
6    M    50    Cat10
7    Z    20     Cat2
> merge(DF, lookup, by = "Name", sort = FALSE)
  Name Count Category
1    A   100     Cat1
2    C    10     Cat2
3    D    40     Cat1
4    E    30     Cat3
5    H     3     Cat3
6    Z    20     Cat2
7    M    50    Cat10
```

---

One option is indexing:

```
foo <- function(x) {
    out <- character(length = length(x))
    chars <- c("Ones", "Tens", "Hundreds", "Thousands")
    out[x < 10] <- chars[1]
    out[x >= 10 & x < 100] <- chars[2]
    out[x >= 100 & x < 1000] <- chars[3]
    out[x >= 1000 & x < 10000] <- chars[4]
    return(factor(out, levels = chars))
}
```

An alternative that scales better is,

```
bar <- function(x, cats = c("Ones", "Tens", "Hundreds", "Thousands")) {
    out <- cats[floor(log10(x)) + 1]
    factor(out, levels = cats)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check out:

- `cut()`
- `recode()` in the `car` package

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps simpler and more readable using ifelse and %in%:

```
df <- data.frame( Name = c('A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'H', 'Z', 'M'), 
Count =c(100,10,40,30,3,20,50), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

cat1 = c("A","D")
cat2 = c("C","Z")
cat3 = c("E","H")
cat10 = c("M")

df$Category = ifelse(df$Name %in% cat1, "Cat1",
              ifelse(df$Name %in% cat2, "Cat2",
              ifelse(df$Name %in% cat3, "Cat3",
              ifelse(df$Name %in% cat10, "Cat10",
              NA))))

   Name Count Category
1    A   100     Cat1
2    C    10     Cat2
3    D    40     Cat1
4    E    30     Cat3
5    H     3     Cat3
6    Z    20     Cat2
7    M    50    Cat10
```