# Case Statement Equivalent in R

Tags: r, case

I have a variable in a dataframe where one of the fields typically has 7-8 values.  I want to collpase them 3 or 4 new categories within a new variable within the dataframe.  What is the best approach?

I would use a CASE statement if I were in a SQL-like tool but not sure how to attack this in R.

Any help you can provide will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 58):

`case_when()`, which was added to dplyr in May 2016, solves this problem in a manner similar to `memisc::cases()`.

As of dplyr 0.7.0, for example:

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(category = case_when(
    cyl == 4 & disp < median(disp) ~ "4 cylinders, small displacement",
    cyl == 8 & disp > median(disp) ~ "8 cylinders, large displacement",
    TRUE ~ "other"
  )
)
```

---

Original answer

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(category = case_when(
    .$cyl == 4 & .$disp < median(.$disp) ~ "4 cylinders, small displacement",
    .$cyl == 8 & .$disp > median(.$disp) ~ "8 cylinders, large displacement",
    TRUE ~ "other"
  )
)
```

Comment: You don't need the `.$` in front of each column.

Comment: Yes, as of dplyr 0.7.0 (released June 9, 2017), the `.$` is no longer necessary. At the time this answer was originally written, it was.

Comment: great solution. 
if both statements are true. Is the second one overwriting the first one?

Comment: @JdP It works just like CASE WHEN in SQL, so the statements are evaluated in order, and the result is the first TRUE statement. (So in the example above, I've put in a TRUE at the end, which serves as a default value.)

Comment: I like this answer because, unlike `switch`, it allows you to create a sequence of expressions instead of keys for the cases.

Answer (score 32):

Here's a way using the `switch` statement:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c('cow','pig','eagle','pigeon'), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$type <- sapply(df$name, switch, 
                  cow = 'animal', 
                  pig = 'animal', 
                  eagle = 'bird', 
                  pigeon = 'bird')

> df
    name   type
1    cow animal
2    pig animal
3  eagle   bird
4 pigeon   bird
```

The one downside of this is that you have to keep writing the category name (`animal`, etc) for each item. It is syntactically more convenient to be able to define our categories as below (see the very similar question [How do add a column in a data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4562547/how-do-add-a-column-in-a-data-frame-in-r/4562655#4562655) )

```
myMap <- list(animal = c('cow', 'pig'), bird = c('eagle', 'pigeon'))
```

and we want to somehow "invert" this mapping. I write my own invMap function:

```
invMap <- function(map) {
  items <- as.character( unlist(map) )
  nams <- unlist(Map(rep, names(map), sapply(map, length)))
  names(nams) <- items
  nams
}
```

and then invert the above map as follows:

```
> invMap(myMap)
     cow      pig    eagle   pigeon 
"animal" "animal"   "bird"   "bird"
```

And then it's easy to use this to add the `type` column in the data-frame:

```
df <- transform(df, type = invMap(myMap)[name])

> df
    name   type
1    cow animal
2    pig animal
3  eagle   bird
4 pigeon   bird
```

Comment: This was really easy and straight forward, thanks for this.

Answer (score 31):

Have a look at the `cases` function from the `memisc` package. It implements case-functionality with two different ways to use it.
From the examples in the package:

```
z1=cases(
    "Condition 1"=x<0,
    "Condition 2"=y<0,# only applies if x >= 0
    "Condition 3"=TRUE
    )
```

where `x` and `y` are two vectors.

References: [memisc package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/memisc/memisc.pdf), [cases example](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/memisc/versions/0.11-9/topics/cases)

Answer (score 30):

I see no proposal for 'switch'. Code example (run it):

```
x <- "three"
y <- 0
switch(x,
       one = {y <- 5},
       two = {y <- 12},
       three = {y <- 432})
y
```

Answer (score 26):

If you got `factor` then you could change levels by standard method:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c('cow','pig','eagle','pigeon'), 
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$type <- factor(df$name) # First step: copy vector and make it factor
# Change levels:
levels(df$type) <- list(
    animal = c("cow", "pig"),
    bird = c("eagle", "pigeon")
)
df
#     name   type
# 1    cow animal
# 2    pig animal
# 3  eagle   bird
# 4 pigeon   bird
```

You could write simple function as a wrapper:

```
changelevels <- function(f, ...) {
    f <- as.factor(f)
    levels(f) <- list(...)
    f
}

df <- data.frame(name = c('cow','pig','eagle','pigeon'), 
                 stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

df$type <- changelevels(df$name, animal=c("cow", "pig"), bird=c("eagle", "pigeon"))
```

Comment: Nice answer. I forgot you could use a list as the argument to levels with the old and the new names like that; my solution depends on one keeping the order of the levels straight, so this is better in that way.

Comment: Also, should the `x` in the last line be `changelevels`?

Answer (score 17):

Imho, most straightforward and universal code:

```
dft=data.frame(x = sample(letters[1:8], 20, replace=TRUE))
dft=within(dft,{
    y=NA
    y[x %in% c('a','b','c')]='abc'
    y[x %in% c('d','e','f')]='def'
    y[x %in% 'g']='g'
    y[x %in% 'h']='h'
})
```

Comment: I like this method. However, is there an 'else' implementation as in some circumstances this would be indispensable

Comment: @T.Fung You can change first line to `y = 'else'`. Elements which don't satisfy to any further conditions will remain unchanged.

Answer (score 10):

There is a `switch` statement but I can never seem to get it to work the way I think it should. Since you have not provided an example I will make one using a factor variable:

```
 dft <-data.frame(x = sample(letters[1:8], 20, replace=TRUE))
 levels(dft$x)
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h"
```

If you specify the categories you want in an order appropriate to the reassignment you can use the factor or numeric variables as an index:

```
c("abc", "abc", "abc", "def", "def", "def", "g", "h")[dft$x]
 [1] "def" "h"   "g"   "def" "def" "abc" "h"   "h"   "def" "abc" "abc" "abc" "h"   "h"   "abc"
[16] "def" "abc" "abc" "def" "def"

dft$y <- c("abc", "abc", "abc", "def", "def", "def", "g", "h")[dft$x] str(dft)
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x: Factor w/ 8 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 4 8 7 4 6 1 8 8 5 2 ...
 $ y: chr  "def" "h" "g" "def" ...
```

I later learned that there really are two different switch functions. It's not generic function but you should think about it as either `switch.numeric` or `switch.character`. If your first argument is an R 'factor', you get `switch.numeric` behavior, which is likely to cause problems, since most people see factors displayed as character and make the incorrect assumption that all functions will process them as such.

Answer (score 8):

I am using in those cases you are referring `switch()`. It looks like a control statement but actually, it is a function. The expression is evaluated and based on this value, the corresponding item in the list is returned.

> switch works in two distinct ways depending whether the first argument evaluates to a character string or a number.

What follows is a simple string example which solves your problem to collapse old categories to new ones.

> For the character-string form, have a single unnamed argument as the default after the named values.

```
newCat <- switch(EXPR = category,
       cat1   = catX,
       cat2   = catX,
       cat3   = catY,
       cat4   = catY,
       cat5   = catZ,
       cat6   = catZ,
       "not available")
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use recode from the car package:

```
library(ggplot2) #get data
library(car)
daimons$new_var <- recode(diamonds$clarity , "'I1' = 'low';'SI2' = 'low';else = 'high';")[1:10]
```

Comment: I just can't support a function that parses it's parameters from text

Comment: Yes, but do you know if anyone has written a better version? `sos::findFn("recode")` finds `doBy::recodeVar`, `epicalc::recode`, `memisc::recode`, but I haven't looked at them in detail ...

Answer (score 5):

i dont like any of these, they are not clear to the reader or the potential user. I just use an anonymous function, the syntax is not as slick as a case statement, but the evaluation is similar to a case statement and not that painful. this also assumes your evaluating it within where your variables are defined.

```
result <- ( function() { if (x==10 | y< 5) return('foo') 
                         if (x==11 & y== 5) return('bar')
                        })()
```

all of those () are necessary to enclose and evaluate the anonymous function.

Comment: 1) The function part is unnecessary; you could just do `result <- (if (x==10 | y< 5) 'foo' else if (x==11 & y== 5) 'bar' )`.  2) This only works if `x` and `y` are scalars; for vectors, as in the original question, nested `ifelse` statements would be necessary.

Answer (score 4):

As of data.table [v1.13.0](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#datatable-v1130--24-jul-2020) you can use the function `fcase()` (fast-case) to do SQL-like `CASE` operations (also similar to `dplyr::case_when()`):

```r
require(data.table)

dt <- data.table(name = c('cow','pig','eagle','pigeon','cow','eagle'))
dt[ , category := fcase(name %in% c('cow', 'pig'), 'mammal',
                        name %in% c('eagle', 'pigeon'), 'bird') ]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have sql-like syntax you can just make use of `sqldf` package. Tthe function to be used is also names `sqldf` and the syntax is as follows

```
sqldf(<your query in quotation marks>)
```

Answer (score 2):

A case statement actually might not be the right approach here.  If this is a factor, which is likely is, just set the levels of the factor appropriately.

Say you have a factor with the letters A to E, like this.

```
> a <- factor(rep(LETTERS[1:5],2))
> a
 [1] A B C D E A B C D E
Levels: A B C D E
```

To join levels B and C and name it BC, just change the names of those levels to BC.

```
> levels(a) <- c("A","BC","BC","D","E")
> a
 [1] A  BC BC D  E  A  BC BC D  E 
Levels: A BC D E
```

The result is as desired.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `base` function `merge` for case-style remapping tasks:

```r
df <- data.frame(name = c('cow','pig','eagle','pigeon','cow','eagle'), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

mapping <- data.frame(
  name=c('cow','pig','eagle','pigeon'),
  category=c('mammal','mammal','bird','bird')
)

merge(df,mapping)
# name category
# 1    cow   mammal
# 2    cow   mammal
# 3  eagle     bird
# 4  eagle     bird
# 5    pig   mammal
# 6 pigeon     bird
```

Answer (score 2):

Mixing `plyr::mutate`  and  `dplyr::case_when` works for me and is readable.

```
iris %>%
plyr::mutate(coolness =
     dplyr::case_when(Species  == "setosa"     ~ "not cool",
                      Species  == "versicolor" ~ "not cool",
                      Species  == "virginica"  ~ "super awesome",
                      TRUE                     ~ "undetermined"
       )) -> testIris
head(testIris)
levels(testIris$coolness)  ## NULL
testIris$coolness <- as.factor(testIris$coolness)
levels(testIris$coolness)  ## ok now
testIris[97:103,4:6]
```

Bonus points if the column can come out of mutate as a factor instead of char!  The last line of the case_when statement, which catches all un-matched rows is very important.

```
     Petal.Width    Species      coolness
 97         1.3  versicolor      not cool
 98         1.3  versicolor      not cool  
 99         1.1  versicolor      not cool
100         1.3  versicolor      not cool
101         2.5  virginica     super awesome
102         1.9  virginica     super awesome
103         2.1  virginica     super awesome
```

Answer (score 2):

```
com = '102'
switch (com,
    '110' = (com= '23279'),
    '101' = (com='23276'),
    '102'= (com = '23277'),
    '111' = (com = '23281'),
    '112' = (com = '23283')
)

print(com)
```

Comment: This answer is really similar to another from 2016. Can you include additional information or elaborate on how this answer is different than the others?

Comment: it is different as it is a proxy for a switch on a numeric case. (switch does not work on a numeric case; or more precisely, works differently)

Answer (score 0):

It is often easier to use a (small) reference table to map the classifications and makes it easier for (non R) people to follow. You can even set up a table to map concatenated variables. You can set up multiple columns as well, obviously.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).