# R add a column to a dataset depending on a function

Tags: r

I have a dataset and I want to insert a new column to it depending on some other columns.

I did this:

```
addGoodnessCustomerClass <- function(Amount, Age){
  if((Amount > 90)&& (Age > 23) && (Age < 44))
    return (c("VIP"))
  return (c("BAD"))
}

cbind(cards, lapply(X = cards, FUN = addGoodnessCustomerClass(cards$Amount, cards$Age)))
```

I got error message:

```
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode="function", envir = envir):
object 'BAD' of mode 'function' was not found
```

help please

Comment: Why are you returning `c("VIP")` in your custom function?  Why not return just the raw string?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i already tried that, and I got the same error

Comment: Have you tried using `sapply()` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes I did and also the exact same error, though in my sitatuion, it seems lapply is the correct function

Comment: This is totally what the `ifelse` (or `switch`) function was designed for. See @cr1msonB1ade's answer.

Comment: @smci even though I showed you what would look like an if else, but actually in my real code, i have more than 7 if statements

Comment: Oh ok then. Always helps to add a comment *"the actual code here is more complicated.."*

Comment: @maybe a comment would have been a better description. anyway, can you help here please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `apply()` function in row mode (second parameter set to 1):

```
addGoodnessCustomerClass <- function(Amount, Age) {
    if ((Amount > 90)&& (Age > 23) && (Age < 44))
        return ("VIP")
    return ("BAD")
}

old.num.cols <- ncol(cards)   # remember number of columns before cbind
cbind(cards, apply(cards[,c('Amount','Age')],
                   1,
                   function(y) addGoodnessCustomerClass(y['Amount'],y['Age'])))
```

To name the new column you can explicitly set it like this:

```
colnames(cards)[old.num.cols+1] <- "CustomerClass"
```

Comment: i am not able to run the first line, which is `lapply`, i got the exact same error message that I have stated in the question

Comment: Using `apply` as I have it above should work for you.

Comment: it works, thank you, but what does the `1` mean , plus, how can I put a name to this new added column please? (accepted answer)

Comment: The `1` here is the margin that the function is being applied along, i.e. it indicates that the function should be applied to elements in each row. (A 2 here would indicate applying a function to elements of each column.)  To add a named column to your dataframe, instead of using `cbind`, you can just do `df$newname <- apply(...)`

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't really need a "function" but a test to determine the new column. You can do this with an `ifelse` call. How about this:

```
cbind.data.frame(cards, AccountClass=cases("VIP"=cards$Amount > 90 & cards$Age > 23 & cards$Age < 44, "OKAY"=cards$Amount > 50 & cards$Age>30, "BAD"=TRUE)
```

Note the cbind.data.frame as cbind will return a matrix, which I am guessing you don't want.

Comment: even though I showed you what would look like an if else, but actually in my real code, i have more than 7 if statements , so I really need a separated function.

Comment: Still this is the right design as @smci said. Try the `cases` function from the `memisc` package. i.e. `cases(
    "VIP"=cards$Amount>90 ,
    "OKAY"=cards$Amount > 50, "BAD"=TRUE)` See previous SO post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622060/case-statement-equivalent-in-r

Comment: thanks, but still you are not using the `Age` variable, anyway, i got an answer, thanks for the help

Comment: I made an edit to show how you can use cases to apply multiple tests and multiple classes and name that column in a much simpler and more readable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the root of your errors is the following (from the `lapply` help page):

> Function FUN must be able to accept as input any of the elements of X. If the latter is an atomic vector, FUN will always be passed a length-one vector of the same type as X.

When you call `lapply()` on a dataframe, you are asking R to apply some function to each column of the dataframe (which of course is not your goal here).

Generally to operate on multiple columns, you will instead want to use `apply`, which can work on an array (not just a list)