# Generic scoring R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, scoring

I'm new to R and moving from sql. I have a problem, where I'm trying to replace sql-case when statements with R. At a high level, I have a input data frame and a reference table. I create computed columns based on the ref. table Example Input data

```
 ------------+-----------+----+------------+-----+------+ |
  STUDENT_ID | UG_MAJOR  | C1 |     C2     | C3  |  C4  |
+------------+-----------+----+------------+-----+------+
|        123 | MATH      | A  | 8000-10000 | 12% | 9000 |
|        234 | ALL_OTHER | B  | 1500-2000  | 10% | 1500 |
|        345 | ALL_OTHER | A  | 2800-3000  | 8%  | 2300 |
|        456 | ALL_OTHER | A  | 8000-10000 | 12% | 3200 |
|        980 | ALL_OTHER | C  | 1000-2500  | 15% | 2700 |
+------------+-----------+----+------------+-----+------+
```

Ref Data

```
> UG_MAJOR  REF_COL REF_VAL REF_SCORE
>     MATH  C1  A   10
>     MATH  C1  B   20
>     MATH  C1  C   30
>     MATH  C1  NULL    0
>     MATH  C1  MISSING 0
>     ALL_OTHER C1  A   20
>     ALL_OTHER C1  B   30
>     ALL_OTHER C1  C   40
>     ALL_OTHER C1  NULL    10
>     ALL_OTHER C1  MISSING 10
>     DEFAULT   C2  <1000   0
>     DEFAULT   C2  >1000   20
>     DEFAULT   C2  >7000   30
>     DEFAULT   C2  >9500   40
>     DEFAULT   C2  MISSING 0
>     DEFAULT   C2  NULL    0
>     DEFAULT   C3  <3% 5
>     DEFAULT   C3  >3% 10
>     DEFAULT   C3  >5% 100
>     DEFAULT   C3  >7% 200
>     DEFAULT   C3  >10%    300
>     DEFAULT   C3  NULL    0
>     DEFAULT   C3  MISSING 0
>     DEFAULT   C4  <5000   10
>     DEFAULT   C4  >5000   20
>     DEFAULT   C4  >10000  30
>     DEFAULT   C4  >15000  40
```

Expected output

```
----------+-----------+----+------------+-----+------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
| Req.Output |           |    |            |     |      |        |        |        |         |
+------------+-----------+----+------------+-----+------+--------+--------

+--------+---------+
| STUDENT_ID | UG_MAJOR  | C1 | C2         | C3  | C4   | C1_SCR | C2_SCR | C3_SCR | TOT_SCR |
| 123        | MATH      | A  | 8000-10000 | 12% | 9000 |  10      |        |        |         |
| 234        | ALL_OTHER | B  | 1500-2000  | 10% | 1500 |  20     |        |        |         |
| 345        | ALL_OTHER | A  | 2800-3000  | 8%  | 2300 |  10     |        |        |         |
| 456        | ALL_OTHER | A  | 8000-10000 | 12% | 3200 |  30     |        |        |         |
| 980        | ALL_OTHER | C  | 1000-2500  | 15% | 2700 |  40      |        |        |         |
+------------+-----------+----+------------+-----+------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
```

Traditional SQL way is

```
select student_id, 
UG_MAJOR, 
C1,
case 
when UG_MAJOR ='MATH' AND when C1 IS NULL THEN 0
when UG_MAJOR ='MATH' AND when C1 ='MISSING' THEN 0
when UG_MAJOR ='MATH' AND when C1 ='A' THEN 10
when UG_MAJOR ='MATH' AND when C1 ='B' THEN 20
when UG_MAJOR ='MATH' AND when C1 ='C' THEN 30

when UG_MAJOR ='ALL_OTHER' AND when C1 IS NULL THEN 0
when UG_MAJOR ='ALL_OTHER' AND when C1 ='MISSING' THEN 0
when UG_MAJOR ='ALL_OTHER' AND when C1 ='A' THEN 20
when UG_MAJOR ='ALL_OTHER' AND when C1 ='B' THEN 30
when UG_MAJOR ='ALL_OTHER' AND when C1 ='C' THEN 40

ELSE 'TBD' END AS C1_SCR,

C2,
CASE 
WHEN C2 IS NULL THEN 0
WHEN C2 ='Missing' OR C2 = . THEN 0
WHEN C2<=1000 THEN 0
WHEN C2 >1000 AND C2<=7000 THEN 20
WHEN C2 >7000 AND C2<=9500 THEN 30
WHEN C2 >9500 THEN 40
ELSE 'TBD' 
END AS C2_SCR

FROM REF_INPUT
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6
```

I'm wondering if there is an elegant way to handle in R ? Thanks Par

Comment: The R `switch` function is analogous to the case operation in SQL. I'm unable to make sense of your question, however. It's difficult to believe that all those new columns should be blank. If you want R answers, you should post R data objects with `dput(.) `so there is no ambiguity about their eventual structure after you finished the needed data input.

Comment: Modified output data frame for C1_SCR.Question is more on the lines--Is there any way to avoid hardcoding the values using conditional logic. Instead use r method to compute the score given the ref.data and input data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Case Statement Equivalent in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622060/case-statement-equivalent-in-r)

Comment: Looks to me that your data is not normalized. How are we supposed to match up with  the ref_data when that matching criteria can choose either  `(C1      | A       |      10 )` or `(C1      | A       |      20 )`?

Comment: Hi..I ws missing one column. If the UG major is math then apply the first block C1-A-10...If it is default apply C1--A-20 scale..For others like C2, C3.the scale is independent of UG major (I denoted this using "default" ).

Answer (score 1):

I think **your solution is a simple "join" between the input data table and the reference table using multiple columns** even though your SQL code in the question does not indicate this but shows a "hard coded" reference table.

Using the package `data.table` the solution could be the last line in this code (the rest is required to create the data of your question):

```
library(data.table)

# your data
input <- setDT(structure(list(STUDENT_ID = c(123L, 234L, 345L, 456L, 980L), 
                        UG_MAJOR = c("MATH", "ALL_OTHER", "ALL_OTHER", "ALL_OTHER", "ALL_OTHER"),
                        C1 = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "C"),
                        C2 = c("8000-10000", "1500-2000", "2800-3000", "8000-10000", "1000-2500"),
                        C3 = c("12%", "10%", "8%", "12%", "15%"),
                        C4 = c(9000L, 1500L, 2300L, 3200L, 2700L)),
                        .Names = c("STUDENT_ID", "UG_MAJOR", "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4"),
                        class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L)))
input

# this is an incomplete list of your reference data (for demo purposes only)
refdata <-
  setDT(structure(
    list(
      UG_MAJOR = c(
        "MATH", "MATH", "MATH", "MATH", "MATH",
        "ALL_OTHER", "ALL_OTHER", "ALL_OTHER", "ALL_OTHER", "ALL_OTHER"
      ), REF_COL = c("C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1",
                     "C1", "C1"), REF_VAL = c("A", "B", "C", "NULL", "MISSING", "A",
                                              "B", "C", "NULL", "MISSING"), REF_SCORE = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 0L,
                                                                                          0L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 10L, 10L)
    ), .Names = c("UG_MAJOR", "REF_COL",
                  "REF_VAL", "REF_SCORE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-10L)
  ))
refdata

# Join your data to the reference data table using multiple join columns and add a new column to input containing the score
input[refdata[REF_COL=="C1",], C1_SCR := REF_SCORE, on=c(UG_MAJOR="UG_MAJOR", C1="REF_VAL") ][]
```

Result:

```
   STUDENT_ID  UG_MAJOR C1         C2  C3   C4 C1_SCR
1:        123      MATH  A 8000-10000 12% 9000     10
2:        234 ALL_OTHER  B  1500-2000 10% 1500     30
3:        345 ALL_OTHER  A  2800-3000  8% 2300     20
4:        456 ALL_OTHER  A 8000-10000 12% 3200     20
5:        980 ALL_OTHER  C  1000-2500 15% 2700     40
```

**Open issues**:

- The result scores in your question seem to be different from mine
  (have you really created the results using your reference data?)
- Setting lookup failures to 0 (value "zero") is not implemented (will 
  be NA, but NA could be replaced by 0 in a second step)
- To create
  the other columns C2_SCR, C3_SCR and C4_SCR you have to apply the
  same logic (from the last line of code)

Comment: Hi I created  the output manually for demo purpose..The join is good for discrete variables. The issue is the scoring can be for discrete or a continuous variable or a range. I was wondering if there is a generic way to sense the variable type and apply the scoring scale

Comment: Yes, you can extend the lookup to use a value range but I do not understand the example data completely (the SQL code considers a range using values in C2 - e. g. "C2 >1000 AND C2<=7000" -  but the input data contain a range in C2 instead of a value, e. g. "1500-2000"). And the ref table did not contain a range but an expression in the ref value. So: It seems to me you want to replace hard coded SQL expressions by expressions that are stored in (ref table) columns? Is that your question? It would be helpful if you edit your question to show more examples...