# How to write an efficient function with multiple conditions in R

Tags: r, function, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am writing an R function to carry out this operation 
[image]

I am particularly wondering the best way to deal with the 2nd condition.
I am currently using `if` statements within a function; the 2nd condition is dealt with using a nested `if` statement.
I am curious if this is the best (fastest, most elegant) way to deal with this type of mathematical functions.

```
#Parameters
K.bc <- 10;K.bk<-100
W2.fg <- W2.fp <- 1000


#Function
F.2.sink <- function(K.bc, K.bk, W2.fg,W2.fp){ 
  if(W2.fg + W2.fg < K.bc) 
  {return(0)}

  if(K.bc < (W2.fg + W2.fg)) 
    if( W2.fg + W2.fg < (K.bc+K.bk))
       {return(W2.fg + W2.fp - K.bc)}

  if(W2.fg + W2.fp >= (K.bc+K.bk))
  {return(K.bk)}
}

F.2.sink(K.bc,K.bk,W2.fg,W2.fp)
```

Comment: When checking your second condition you already checked that it didn't meet the first condition. You don't need another if to check that same thing again.

Comment: Also code review questions like this should probably be posted at the code review site and not here.

Comment: @Dason I don't think this really belongs on CR, he is only asking about one thing. We wouldn't turn him down, but probably not the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at:
[Case Statement Equivalent in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622060/case-statement-equivalent-in-r)
There is this function `cases` in package `memisc`
Not sure about fastness, but at least more readable.