# How to measure proportions sequentially?

Tags: r

I am trying to measure the Response rate for certain recruitment strategies.
Recruitment took place over 30 waves. For each wave, potential participants were sent an Invitation letter, which they could answer with "yes" or "no". Sometimes These subjects would not answer the Invitation, where they would receive a reminder letter, which they could answer in a similar manner. They would receive up to 3 reminders.

My dataset has a variable for each reminder with values 0 and 1.

So if a certain participant received only an Invitation (and answered with "yes or no") he/ she would be given value "0" for first reminder, "0" for second reminder, and "0" for third reminder.

I am trying to measure the Response rate (People that said yes) after receiving the Invitation, or first reminder, or second and so forth.

Which means People that said yes after the Invitation letter / all of those that received the Invitation letter (which is basically everyone). And People that said yes after the first reminder /  all those who received the first reminder( regardless if they received the second reminder and minus those who said yes or no to the Invitation letter).

My dataset Looks like this:

```
ID wave participate freminder sreminder treminder 
   267  1       yes        0          0          0
   312  1       no         0          0          0
   516  29      yes        1          1          1
```

I created a new variable "Group"

```
datnakwtele$group[which( datnakwtele$freminder == "0" )] <-1
datnakwtele$group[which(datnakwtele$freminder == "1" & datnakwtele$sreminder == "0" )] <- 2
datnakwtele$group[which( datnakwtele$freminder == "1" & datnakwtele$sreminder >= "1" & datnakwtele$treminder == "0"  )] <- 3
datnakwtele$group[which( datnakwtele$freminder == "1" & datnakwtele$sreminder >= "1" & datnakwtele$treminder >= "1" )] <- 4
```

Then I did this

````
dplyr::group_by(wave,group,participate) %>%
dplyr::summarise (n = n()) %>%
dplyr::mutate(Percentage = (((n/ sum(n)*100))))
 ```

But my Output only (for example) Shows People that said yes after the first Invitation / People that only responded to the first Invitation (and not everyone that received it)


```wave  group participate     n Percentage
1 1     1     yes             64      50.4 
2 1     1     no              63      49.6 
3 1     2     yes             32      36.4 
4 1     2     no              55      62.5 
6 1     3     yes             11      18.6
````

Lets say 100 People received the Invitation ,5 subjects answered yes, and another 5 answered no. The Response rate should be 5/100, and not 5/10. 90 subjects did not respond and received the first reminder, again 5 said yes and 5 said no. The Response rate for the first reminder should be 5/ 90 (100-those who answered the Invitation)

Comment: My guess is your grouping function logic is not catching all situations. Do you mean to use `==` instead of `>=`. Inspect the group for NAs. Initialize the group variable before using (ex `datnakwtele$group<-0` ). Check out the `case_when` [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622060/case-statement-equivalent-in-r/41866620#41866620) [2](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) function as an alternative to using multiple `which` statements.

Comment: Can you post the output of `datnakwtele %>% group_by(group, participate) %>% summarise(count = n())`? I just want to make sure the values exist for each pairing. Also, it might be easier to create your groups using dplyr and `ifelse`. It's good practice and makes everything more human readable

Comment: ```Groups:   group [8]
   group participate count
   <dbl> <fct>       <int>
 1     0 yes           2880
 2     0 no         1161
 3     0 open         499
 4     1 yes           1507
 5     1 no         3349
 6     1 open         329
 7     2 yes            849
 8     2 no         4994
 9     2 open         490
10     3 yes            311```

Comment: the Code above is just an example, the ```>=``` is done for the People that received more than 1 "second reminder" because the address was wrong or so. No NAs exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## EDIT no. 3, I think I got the problem now

---

Is this maybe a solution?

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(ID = sample(letters,100, T), 
               wave = sample(1:30, 100, T),
               answer = sample(c('yes', 'no'),100,T),
               freminder = rbinom(100,1,.5),
               sreminder = rbinom(100,1,.5),
               treminder = rbinom(100,1,.5))
# group as sum
data$group <- data  %>% select(freminder, sreminder, treminder) %>% rowSums()

# split into seperate wave-sets
spData <- split(data, data$wave)

# define what to to per wave
returnFreqs <- function(wave){
  tab <- table(wave$group, wave$answer)
  num <- rev(cumsum(rev(rowSums(tab))))
  list(absFreq = tab,
       relFreq = sweep(tab,
                       MARGIN = 1,
                       STATS = num,
                       FUN = '/'))
}

allTabs <- lapply(spData, returnFreqs)
```

Creating the following output in `allTabs`:

```
#> $`2`
#> $`2`$absFreq
#>    
#>     no yes
#>   1  1   0
#>   2  1   0
#>   3  1   1
#> 
#> $`2`$relFreq
#>    
#>            no       yes
#>   1 0.2500000 0.0000000
#>   2 0.3333333 0.0000000
#>   3 0.5000000 0.5000000
#> 
#> 
#> $`3`
#> $`3`$absFreq
#>    
#>     no yes
#>   1  1   0
#>   2  2   2
#> 
#> $`3`$relFreq
#>    
#>      no yes
#>   1 0.2 0.0
#>   2 0.5 0.5
#> 
#> 
#> $`4`
#> $`4`$absFreq
#>    
#>     no
#>   1  1
#> 
#> $`4`$relFreq
#>    
#>     no
#>   1  1
#> 
#> 
#> $`5`
#> $`5`$absFreq
#>    
#>     no yes
#>   1  1   0
#>   2  2   1
#>   3  1   0
#> 
#> $`5`$relFreq
#>    
#>       no  yes
#>   1 0.20 0.00
#>   2 0.50 0.25
#>   3 1.00 0.00
#> 
#> 
#> $`6`
#> $`6`$absFreq
#>    
#>     no
#>   1  1
#> 
#> $`6`$relFreq
#>    
#>     no
#>   1  1
#> 
#> 
#> $`7`
#> $`7`$absFreq
#>    
#>     yes
#>   0   1
#>   2   1
#> 
#> $`7`$relFreq
#>    
#>     yes
#>   0 0.5
#>   2 1.0
#> 
#> 
#> $`8`
#> $`8`$absFreq
#>    
#>     no yes
#>   1  0   1
#>   2  1   1
#> 
#> $`8`$relFreq
#>    
#>            no       yes
#>   1 0.0000000 0.3333333
#>   2 0.5000000 0.5000000
#> 
#> 
#> $`9`
#> $`9`$absFreq
#>    
#>     no yes
#>   1  0   1
#>   2  2   0
#> 
#> $`9`$relFreq
#>    
#>            no       yes
#>   1 0.0000000 0.3333333
#>   2 1.0000000 0.0000000
#> 
#> 
#> $`10`
#> $`10`$absFreq
#>    
#>     no yes
#>   1  0   1
#>   2  2   0
#> 
#> $`10`$relFreq
#>    
#>            no       yes
#>   1 0.0000000 0.3333333
#>   2 1.0000000 0.0000000
#> 
#> 
#> $`11`
#> $`11`$absFreq
#>    
#>     no yes
#>   0  0   1
#>   1  1   1
#>   3  1   0
#> 
#> $`11`$relFreq
#>    
#>            no       yes
#>   0 0.0000000 0.2500000
#>   1 0.3333333 0.3333333
#>   3 1.0000000 0.0000000
#> 
#> 
#> $`12`
#> $`12`$absFreq
#>    
#>     no yes
#>   2  1   1
#>   3  0   1
#> 
#> $`12`$relFreq
#>    
#>            no       yes
#>   2 0.3333333 0.3333333
#>   3 0.0000000 1.0000000
#> 
#> 
#> $`13`
#> $`13`$absFreq
#>    
#>     no yes
#>   2  0   1
#>   3  1   0
#> 
#> $`13`$relFreq
#>    
#>      no yes
#>   2 0.0 0.5
#>   3 1.0 0.0
#> 
#> 
#> $`14`
#> $`14`$absFreq
#>    
#>     no yes
#>   1  1   2
#>   2  1   2
#> 
#> $`14`$relFreq
#>    
#>            no       yes
#>   1 0.1666667 0.3333333
#>   2 0.3333333 0.6666667
#> 
#> 
#> $`15`
#> $`15`$absFreq
#>    
#>     yes
#>   0   2
#>   1   1
#> 
#> $`15`$relFreq
#>    
#>           yes
#>   0 0.6666667
#>   1 1.0000000
#> 
#> 
#> $`16`
#> $`16`$absFreq
#>    
#>     no yes
#>   0  0   1
#>   1  1   1
#>   2  1   1
#>   3  1   0
#> 
#> $`16`$relFreq
#>    
#>            no       yes
#>   0 0.0000000 0.1666667
#>   1 0.2000000 0.2000000
#>   2 0.3333333 0.3333333
#>   3 1.0000000 0.0000000
#> 
#> 
#> $`17`
#> $`17`$absFreq
#>    
#>     yes
#>   0   1
#> 
#> $`17`$relFreq
#>    
#>     yes
#>   0   1
#> 
#> 
#> $`18`
#> $`18`$absFreq
#>    
#>     no yes
#>   2  1   1
#> 
#> $`18`$relFreq
#>    
#>      no yes
#>   2 0.5 0.5
#> 
#> 
#> $`19`
#> $`19`$absFreq
#>    
#>     no yes
#>   0  0   1
#>   2  1   1
#> 
#> $`19`$relFreq
#>    
#>            no       yes
#>   0 0.0000000 0.3333333
#>   2 0.5000000 0.5000000
#> 
#> 
#> $`20`
#> $`20`$absFreq
#>    
#>     yes
#>   0   1
#>   3   1
#> 
#> $`20`$relFreq
#>    
#>     yes
#>   0 0.5
#>   3 1.0
#> 
#> 
#> $`21`
#> $`21`$absFreq
#>    
#>     no
#>   2  2
#> 
#> $`21`$relFreq
#>    
#>     no
#>   2  1
#> 
#> 
#> $`22`
#> $`22`$absFreq
#>    
#>     no yes
#>   0  0   1
#>   1  2   1
#>   2  1   1
#>   3  0   2
#> 
#> $`22`$relFreq
#>    
#>            no       yes
#>   0 0.0000000 0.1250000
#>   1 0.2857143 0.1428571
#>   2 0.2500000 0.2500000
#>   3 0.0000000 1.0000000
#> 
#> 
#> $`23`
#> $`23`$absFreq
#>    
#>     yes
#>   2   1
#> 
#> $`23`$relFreq
#>    
#>     yes
#>   2   1
#> 
#> 
#> $`24`
#> $`24`$absFreq
#>    
#>     no yes
#>   2  1   3
#>   3  1   1
#> 
#> $`24`$relFreq
#>    
#>            no       yes
#>   2 0.1666667 0.5000000
#>   3 0.5000000 0.5000000
#> 
#> 
#> $`25`
#> $`25`$absFreq
#>    
#>     no yes
#>   1  2   0
#>   2  2   1
#> 
#> $`25`$relFreq
#>    
#>            no       yes
#>   1 0.4000000 0.0000000
#>   2 0.6666667 0.3333333
#> 
#> 
#> $`26`
#> $`26`$absFreq
#>    
#>     no yes
#>   2  2   1
#> 
#> $`26`$relFreq
#>    
#>            no       yes
#>   2 0.6666667 0.3333333
#> 
#> 
#> $`27`
#> $`27`$absFreq
#>    
#>     no yes
#>   1  0   3
#>   2  2   0
#> 
#> $`27`$relFreq
#>    
#>      no yes
#>   1 0.0 0.6
#>   2 1.0 0.0
#> 
#> 
#> $`28`
#> $`28`$absFreq
#>    
#>     no yes
#>   1  1   0
#>   2  0   1
#> 
#> $`28`$relFreq
#>    
#>      no yes
#>   1 0.5 0.0
#>   2 0.0 1.0
#> 
#> 
#> $`29`
#> $`29`$absFreq
#>    
#>     no yes
#>   0  1   0
#>   1  1   2
#> 
#> $`29`$relFreq
#>    
#>            no       yes
#>   0 0.2500000 0.0000000
#>   1 0.3333333 0.6666667
#> 
#> 
#> $`30`
#> $`30`$absFreq
#>    
#>     no yes
#>   0  0   1
#>   2  2   1
#>   3  1   0
#> 
#> $`30`$relFreq
#>    
#>       no  yes
#>   0 0.00 0.20
#>   2 0.50 0.25
#>   3 1.00 0.00
```

Comment: I am afraid not. Lets say 100 People received the Invitation ,5 subjects answered yes, and another 5 answered no. The Response rate should be 5/100, and not 5/10. 90 subjects did not respond and received the first reminder, again 5 said yes and 5 said no. The Response rate for the first reminder should be 5/ 90 (100-those who answered the Invitation)

Comment: What do you think now?

Comment: I also Need it to be stratified for each wave :D. I really appreciate your help. This is the Output I get when I tried to do so ```, ,  = yes

    
                0            1            2            3            4            5            6            7
  1  2.392434e-03 1.196217e-03 3.738178e-04 5.233449e-04 3.738178e-05 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
  2  2.094999e-03 1.333181e-03 4.951815e-04 4.570906e-04 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00
  3  2.330459e-03 1.592480e-03 4.660918e-04 3.495689e-04 3.884099e-05 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00```

Comment: Your problem there is that table with 3 inputs returns a 3D-Matrix. You can solve that problem using ftable. I edited my answer to accomodate you requirement.

Comment: I tried this, I think now the proportions are calculated by dividing the People that said yes in the first wave (Invitation) over the entire Group of People across all 40 waves. the proportions were really small, and got larger as I reached the final wave (as the denominator kept on dropping)

Comment: I'm not sure, I can follow. What is your goal here, to have the amount of people responding per wave and per 'round of invitation'. If yes, my code should work. The `num`-Vector in my example sums up the amount of people that responded per 'round of invitation' increasing over the waves. 
Could you perhaps edit your question adding a made up table showing which output you wish for and what exactly you mean by stratified for each wave?

Comment: I am sorry if I might be doing something wrong, but  ``` (num <- rev(cumsum(rev(rowSums(tab))))) ``` gives me this  ```  26751 26624 26536 26477 26253 26116 26009 25960 25746 25670 25539 25479 25232 25149 25033 24738 24728 24637    ``` I believe These numbers are the total number of People across all 30 waves. If I Limit the dataset to just one wave, then it works for me. I want the total from which the proportions are measured to be per 1 wave. So it would be for example (wave 1) 498,371, 278, 220,(wave 2) 560,456, 311,200, and so forth.

Comment: So instead of going from 100 to 0, it should be 100, 98,96,90, then goes back to 100 for the next wave.

Comment: Ok, I think I get you now. You need to split the data. I'll edit my answer.