# Plotting age in buckets

Tags: r

Trying to print put age groups in "Buckets" bins to use visualization.

I'm trying to group age ranges in each buckets by using ifelse fun, it is populating only Bucket1 and Bucket2. However function has Buckets3 and 4 as well.

Using Titanic_train (data)

```
titc=Titanic_train

titc$buckets = ifelse(titc$age<=20, "Bucket1",
                      ifelse(titc$age>20|titc$age<=40, "Bucket2",
                             ifelse(titc$age>40|titc$age<=60, "Bucket3", "Bucket4")))
```

[image]

I want age has to group by Buckets with help of ifelse, most important if age is blank NA then it has to fall in Bucket1.

Comment: Use `&`, not `|`. *Every number* is greater than 20 **or** less than 40.

Comment: And I agree with @PavoDive ... the moment I consider more than one nested (two total) `ifelse` statements, I look at alternatives. In this case, it is clearly `cut`, as the ranges you're looking at are contiguous, non-overlapping.

Comment: You might like `dplyr::case_when()` function better than nested `ifelse()`. example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622060/case-statement-equivalent-in-r/41866620#41866620

Comment: by using & it is working, however NA are still showing as NA instead it should fall in Bucket 1. Any Idea how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your data is fully reproducible, but the `cut` function does what you want.

Try:

```
cut(titc$age, breaks = c(20, 40, 60))
```

You can add customized labels too. See `?cut`

Comment: This is incomplete, I suggest instead `cut(titc$age, breaks = c(-Inf, 20, 40, 60, Inf), labels = c("Bucket1", "Bucket2", "Bucket3", "Bucket4"))`.

Comment: by using & it is working, however NA are still showing as NA instead it should fall in Bucket 1. Any Idea how to deal with it?