# Losing names when using lists as results of dplyr::case_when

Tags: r, dplyr

Please consider the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
x <- case_when(
   FALSE ~ list('a' = 'b'),
   TRUE  ~ list('c' = 'd')
)
```

x is

List of 1
 $ NA: chr "d"

I expect the element d in x to have the name 'c' and not NA. Am I missing something? Is this a bug? And how can I achieve my expected behavior?

To be precise, I expect above statement to have the same result as

```
x <- list('c' = 'd')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **The following is irrelevant, please skip to the update**

It's not really clear what your expected behavior is from the short code snippet and without sample data.

However it seems to me you have the wrong syntax on `case_when`.

The function works like this:

```r
case_when( Condition 1 ~ Value to be assigned if true,
           Condition 2 ~ Value to be assigned if true
```

The conditions you use are `FALSE`and `TRUE`, this does not really make sense because the following will happen:

```r
x <- case_when(
   FALSE ~ list('a' = 'b'), # FALSE is logically never True, so the value is never put in
   TRUE  ~ list('c' = 'd') # TRUE is always true, x will always be assigned the list
)
```

So first you have to rewrite your conditions to make sense. Secondly you are assigning lists as the return value and I do not think this is correct.

I assume you want to do this:

```r
x <- case_when(
   VAR == 'a' ~ 'b', # If the variable to be evaluated has the value 'a' x will be 'b'
   VAR == 'c' ~ 'd') # If the variable to be evaluated has the value 'c' x will be 'd'
)
```

So this now evaluates an existing variable "VAR" and returns x as determined by your code. Notices that this statement is incomplete, because it will naturally return `NA`for every case where none of the two conditions are met (so VAR is neither 'a' nor 'c').

So normally we complete like this:

```r
x <- case_when(
   VAR == 'a' ~ 'b', # If the variable to be evaluated has the value 'a' x will be 'b'
   VAR == 'c' ~ 'd') # If the variable to be evaluated has the value 'c' x will be 'd'
   TRUE ~ 'Rest Value' # Assigns Rest value to x for all case that do not meet case 1 or 2
)
```

### **Update**

It seems this is a known issue see here:

https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4194

Hadley gives the following solution as an alternative:

```r
broken_function <- function(value) {
  if (value) {
    list(a = 1, b = 2)
  } else {
    lst(a = 2, b = 3)
  }
}
```

Comment: My code is just dummy code. I know that the last condition is always true. Howver, I am only concerned about the result.

Comment: @ACNB Then pay attention to the second part of my answer. Assigning 'c' to 'd' is not done by list but as I have shown: `x == 'd' ~ 'c'`. Your example assigns every value in x a list() object not a specific value. The LHS of ~ is for the condition and the RHS is only for the return value.

Comment: I added some clarification, I hope this helps.

Comment: @ACNB & @IceCreamToucan Thanks, the update helped. I updated my answer, this seems to be a known and wanted issue of `dplyr`. I included the relevant link and Hadley's alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Hadley's solution is in really not to use tidyverse. Here are some more alternatives, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622060/case-statement-equivalent-in-r, I like switch.