# How to do nested for loops with an if

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement

Edit: This question has been answered successfully.

I have a data frame called hispn and a vector of quintiles called qq_hispn. Hispn has two columns of interest named "FAMINC17" which is family income, and "Stimulants."

I'm trying to create a new column called "Stim_Income" that has a different value for the 5 income ranges and whether they are on a stimulant. So if they are between 0-20% of the income range and are on a stimulant, the value is 1. If not on a stimulant, the value is 6. The values should be 2 and 7 for 20-40%, 3 and 8 for 40-60%, etc. This will allow me to compute a prescription prevalence (1/6, 2/7, etc) for each quintile.

I came up with this very amateur method. Can anyone tell me why it is not working?

```
  for (i in 1:5) {
    for (j in nrow(hispn)) {
      if ( (hispn[j,"FAMINC17"]>qq_hispn[i])&&(hispn[j,"FAMINC17"]<=qq_hispn[i+1])&&(hispn[j,"Stimulants"]==1) ) {
        hispn[j,"Stim_Income"]<-i
      } else if ( (hispn[j,"FAMINC17"]>qq_hispn[i])&&(hispn[j,"FAMINC17"]<=qq_hispn[i+1])&&(hispn[j,"Stimulants"]==0) ) {
        hispn[j,"Stim_Income"]<-(i+5)
      }
    }
  }
```

I tried to implement the code that Michelle linked in the comments, but it returned an error.

```
  hispn %>% 
    mutate(Stim_Income = case_when (
      FAMINC17>qq_hispn[1] & FAMINC17<=qq_hispn[2] & Stimulants==1  ~ 1
      FAMINC17>qq_hispn[1] & FAMINC17<=qq_hispn[2] & Stimulants==0  ~ 6
      FAMINC17>qq_hispn[2] & FAMINC17<=qq_hispn[3] & Stimulants==1  ~ 2
      FAMINC17>qq_hispn[2] & FAMINC17<=qq_hispn[3] & Stimulants==0  ~ 7
      FAMINC17>qq_hispn[3] & FAMINC17<=qq_hispn[4] & Stimulants==1  ~ 3
      FAMINC17>qq_hispn[3] & FAMINC17<=qq_hispn[4] & Stimulants==0  ~ 8
      FAMINC17>qq_hispn[4] & FAMINC17<=qq_hispn[5] & Stimulants==1  ~ 4
      FAMINC17>qq_hispn[4] & FAMINC17<=qq_hispn[5] & Stimulants==0  ~ 9
      FAMINC17>qq_hispn[5] & FAMINC17<=qq_hispn[6] & Stimulants==1  ~ 5
      FAMINC17>qq_hispn[5] & FAMINC17<=qq_hispn[6] & Stimulants==0  ~ 10
  
     )
    )
```

Another user asked for reproducible data and an example output.

```
  m1<- matrix(0,ncol=2,nrow=5)
  m1[1,1]=1000
  m1[2,1]=1000
  m1[3,1]=1000
  m1[4,1]=1000
  m1[5,1]=10000
  m1[3,2]=1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 1000    0
[2,] 1000    0
[3,] 1000    1
[4,] 1000    0
[5,] 10000    0
```

And then, here is the new column with the information of interest, if the for loop would have worked. But instead, I got a column of NA.

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 1000    0    6
[2,] 1000    0    6
[3,] 1000    1    5
[4,] 1000    0    6
[5,]    0    0    7
```

Comment: Hi there. Often times what would be a loop in a difference language is solved by something other than a loop in R. Have you looked at the dplyr package? There are some nice solutions in there without having to resort to a loop. I'm familiar with using elseif, however I have seen this as a solution to a problem that appears similar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622060/case-statement-equivalent-in-r

Comment: @Michelle I see. I tried doing it that way, but there seems to be something wrong with my syntax. I pasted it into the original question since it wouldn't fit here. Can you help?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @RonakShah I added the reproducible info with the expected output. Please let me know if you're able to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on some of the details you provided, I created a sample dataset. It does not exactly resemble your data with the quintile vector, but here's my attempt:

```
library(dplyr)

FAMINC17 <- c('0-20','0-20','20-40', '20-40', '40-60', '40-60', '60-80', '60-80', '80-100', '80-100')
Stimulants <- c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)

hispn <- data.frame(FAMINC17, Stimulants)

hispn %>% 
  mutate(Stim_Income = case_when(
    FAMINC17 == "0-20"   & Stimulants == 1 ~ 1,
    FAMINC17 == "0-20"   & Stimulants == 0 ~ 6,
    FAMINC17 == "20-40"  & Stimulants == 1 ~ 2,
    FAMINC17 == "20-40"  & Stimulants == 0 ~ 7,
    FAMINC17 == "40-60"  & Stimulants == 1 ~ 3,
    FAMINC17 == "40-60"  & Stimulants == 0 ~ 8,
    FAMINC17 == "60-80"  & Stimulants == 1 ~ 4,
    FAMINC17 == "60-80"  & Stimulants == 0 ~ 9,
    FAMINC17 == "80-100" & Stimulants == 1 ~ 5,
    FAMINC17 == "80-100" & Stimulants == 0 ~ 10,
  ))
```

Hopefully this works.

Comment: That worked! It won't let me upvote because my reputation is too low, but thank you so much!

Comment: No worries, Danny. Good luck :)

Comment: @Danny If the answer helped you can accept the answer by clicking on checkmark on the left.