# In R is there a better option than a nested if else statement? i would like to have something more cleaner with less parenthesis

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

For example i am using this. though it works I have to put in extra more entries and i can't imagine creating so many parenthesis at the end while my code is shifting to the right.

```
df$col2<-ifelse(df$col1 == "001","Green", 
                       ifelse(df$col1 == "005", "Blue",
                              ifelse(df$col1 == "009", "Yellow",
                                     ifelse(df$col1 == "006", "Pink",
                                            ifelse(df$col1 == "007","Other")))))
```

Is there a better option than doing it this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch? https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/switch-function/

Which would make your example:

```
df$col2<-switch(df$col1, "001" = "Green", "005" = "Blue", "006" = "Pink", "007" = "Other")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622060/case-statement-equivalent-in-r <- or various other possibilities

Comment: I get this error. Are you familiar as to why?
  EXPR must be a length 1 vector

Comment: This is for individual values. You're feeding it a whole column at once? Then see this answer how to apply it to a column: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4626092/14215102

Comment: Yeah i was using for all columns. It worked thank you..