# How to write a function in to a ifelse formula in R?

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I have two functions:

```
METAL <- function(x){
  between(x, 241,259)|
    between(x,271,309)
}

MOTOR <- function(x){
  x == 452|
  x == 454)
}
```

I would like to use the function as a condition in an ifelse formula.

```
DF$SUB <- ifelse(DF$IND == METAL(DF$IND), "Metal", "Other")

DF$SUB <- ifelse(DF$IND == MOTOR(DF$IND), "Motor", DF$SUB)
```

It lables every row as "Other". Even rows where IND == 241 and should be labled as "Metal".

IND contains numbers from 10 to 999

I want to add a new column named SUB to the DF and write in to column "Metal" where column IND is the same as defined in the function METAL, write "Motor" where it is defined as MOTOR and "Other" in all other rows.

How do i put the function in to the ifelse correctly? I need it as a function so that if i  change the parameters it will be changed everywhere in code not just one place.

Thank you

Comment: What is originally in df$IND? Is it empty? Try to post a reprex if possible.

Comment: Your function MOTOR also might have a typo. X vs. x

Comment: IND has numbers from 10 to 999. There is an error in my original code. I had misspelled the column name. I fixed it. Now the code runs but it marks everything as "Other" Even rows where IND == 241. That should be labeled as "Metal"

Comment: `case` is more suitable for this case, no need to create functions, see examples at https://stackoverflow.com/q/4622060/680068

Comment: Remove `DF$IND ==` from ifelse statements.

Comment: Thank you @zx8754 removing it worked. For some reason i was sure I had to have it. Ohh well. I learned something new and useful today :) Thank you so much!

Comment: Great, added cleaner version as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your functions are returning logicals, no need to compare them to IND column anymore.

```
#example data
DF <- data.frame(IND = c(240:243, 260, 451, 452, 454, 455)) 

METAL <- function(x) between(x, 241, 259) | between(x, 271, 309)
MOTOR <- function(x) x == 452 | x == 454

DF$SUB <- ifelse(METAL(DF$IND), "Metal", 
                 ifelse(MOTOR(DF$IND), "Motor", "Other"))

DF
#   IND   SUB
# 1 240 Other
# 2 241 Metal
# 3 242 Metal
# 4 243 Metal
# 5 260 Other
# 6 451 Other
# 7 452 Motor
# 8 454 Motor
# 9 455 Other
```