# Dictionary style replace multiple items

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large data.frame of character data that I want to convert based on what is commonly called a dictionary in other languages.

Currently I am going about it like so:

```
foo <- data.frame(snp1 = c("AA", "AG", "AA", "AA"), snp2 = c("AA", "AT", "AG", "AA"), snp3 = c(NA, "GG", "GG", "GC"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
foo <- replace(foo, foo == "AA", "0101")
foo <- replace(foo, foo == "AC", "0102")
foo <- replace(foo, foo == "AG", "0103")
```

This works fine, but it is obviously not pretty and seems silly to repeat the `replace` statement each time I want to replace one item in the data.frame.

Is there a better way to do this since I have a dictionary of approximately 25 key/value pairs?

Comment: Is your dictionary an R list?

Comment: Not currently, but it would easy to make it into one.

Comment: Maybe this questions could be helpful: [Case Statement Equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4622060/168747), [How to add a column in a `data.frame`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4562547/168747), [Data cleaning in Excel sheets](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7374314/168747).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
map = setNames(c("0101", "0102", "0103"), c("AA", "AC", "AG"))
foo[] <- map[unlist(foo)]
```

assuming that `map` covers all the cases in `foo`. This would feel less like a 'hack' and be more efficient in both space and time if `foo` were a matrix (of character()), then

```
matrix(map[foo], nrow=nrow(foo), dimnames=dimnames(foo))
```

Both matrix and data frame variants run afoul of R's 2^31-1 limit on vector size when there are millions of SNPs and thousands of samples.

Comment: FYI - if you are using `tidyverse` and have foo as a tibble, you have to coerce it to a data.frame prior to assigning `map[unlist(foo)]`, otherwise the row count of assigned vs existing data will differ.

Answer (score 43):

If you're open to using packages, `plyr` is a very popular one and has this handy [mapvalues()](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/plyr/docs/mapvalues) function that will do just what you're looking for:

```
foo <- mapvalues(foo, from=c("AA", "AC", "AG"), to=c("0101", "0102", "0103"))
```

Note that it works for data types of all kinds, not just strings.

Comment: Unfortunately, this throws an _Error in plyr::mapvalues(foo, from = c("AA", "AC", "AG"), to = c("0101",  :  `x` must be an atomic vector._ This also documented in `?mapvalues`.

Comment: This works absolutely well! Thank you c.gutierrez.

Comment: I have the same issue as @Uwe, with a recent R version (4.3.2.) and a recent `plyr` version (1.8.9.). It seems that the function works for vectors, not for an entire dataframe. I would recommend the following code for an entire dataframe `apply(foo, 2, function(x) mapvalues(x, from=c("AA", "AC", "AG"), to=c("0101", "0102", "0103")))`.

Answer (score 19):

Here is a quick solution

```
dict = list(AA = '0101', AC = '0102', AG = '0103')
foo2 = foo
for (i in 1:3){foo2 <- replace(foo2, foo2 == names(dict[i]), dict[i])}
```

Comment: I like this answer because it keeps the keys and values together.  Having the keys and values in separate character vectors means that if you get the order of one of the vectors wrong, your dictionary silently mislabels all incorrectly ordered entries.

Comment: Only difference I would suggest is to use R's vectorized notation on the 3rd line, e.g.: sapply(1:3, function(i) replace(foo2, foo2 == names(dict[i]), dict[i]))

Comment: `*apply` functions are NOT the same as vectorized.

Answer (score 14):

One of the most readable way to replace value in a string or a vector of string with a dictionary is `str_replace_all`, from the `stringr` package. **The 'pattern' argument of `str_replace_all` can be a dictionnary, expressed as a list**: `stringr::str_replace_all(string = dataset$string, pattern = c("regex" = "desired value"))`. This way, no need to specify the 'replacement' argument.

*Beware: this method is based on regex*, which is very useful and flexible (see [here](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html)) but requires attention to what you are doing and to the results obtained (see point #2 in the code below).

```
# 1. Example of dictionnary ↓
      dictio_replace= c("AA" = "0101", 
                        "AC" = "0102",
                        "AG" = "0103") 

   #2 ↓ (OPTIONAL) Add begin & end of string anchors ("^" & "$" in regex) 
   
    names(dictio_replace) = paste0("^", names(dictio_replace), "$")  

      # 3. ↓ Replace all pattern, according to the dictionary-values

 foo$snp1 <- stringr::str_replace_all(string = foo$snp1,
                                      pattern= dictio_replace)  
# ↑ We only use the 'pattern' option here: 'replacement' is useless since we provide a dictionnary.
```

Repeat step #3 with foo$snp2 & foo$snp3. If you have more vectors to transform it's a good idea to use another func' like a `for` loop or `apply` family, in order to replace values in each of the columns/vector in the dataframe without repeating yourself.

Note that without specifying the beginning and the end of the string with `^` & `$` in the regex-dictionnary, "AAAA" will be replaced by "01010101", since "AAAA" contains "AA" twice. With the `^` & `$` anchors surrounding "AA", "AAAA" will not be replaced at all.

Answer (score 8):

In case there is only a vector (or one data frame column)
whose values need to be replaced *and* there are no objections to use factor we can coerce the vector to factor and change the factor levels as required:

```
x <- c(1, 1, 4, 4, 5, 5, 1, 1, 2)
x <- factor(x)
x
#[1] 1 1 4 4 5 5 1 1 2
#Levels: 1 2 4 5
replacement_vec <- c("A", "T", "C", "G")
levels(x) <- replacement_vec
x
#[1] A A C C G G A A T
#Levels: A T C G
```

Using the `forcats`package this can be done in a one-liner:

```
x <- c(1, 1, 4, 4, 5, 5, 1, 1, 2)
forcats::lvls_revalue(factor(x), replacement_vec)
#[1] A A C C G G A A T
#Levels: A T C G
```

---

In case *all* values of multiple columns of a data frame need to be replaced, the approach can be extended.

```
foo <- data.frame(snp1 = c("AA", "AG", "AA", "AA"), 
                  snp2 = c("AA", "AT", "AG", "AA"), 
                  snp3 = c(NA, "GG", "GG", "GC"), 
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

level_vec <- c("AA", "AC", "AG", "AT", "GC", "GG")
replacement_vec <- c("0101", "0102", "0103", "0104", "0302", "0303")
foo[] <- lapply(foo, function(x) forcats::lvls_revalue(factor(x, levels = level_vec), 
                                                       replacement_vec))
foo
#  snp1 snp2 snp3
#1 0101 0101 <NA>
#2 0103 0104 0303
#3 0101 0103 0303
#4 0101 0101 0302
```

Note that `level_vec` and `replacement_vec` must have equal lengths.

More importantly, `level_vec` should be *complete* , i.e., include all possible values in the affected columns of the original data frame. (Use `unique(sort(unlist(foo)))` to verify). Otherwise, any missing values will be coerced to `<NA>`. Note that this is also a requirement for [Martin Morgans's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7548031/3817004).

So, if there are only a few different values to be replaced you will be probably better off with one of the other answers, e.g., [Ramnath's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7547803/3817004).

Answer (score 8):

We can also use `dplyr::case_when`

```
library(dplyr)

foo %>%
   mutate_all(~case_when(. == "AA" ~ "0101", 
                         . == "AC" ~ "0102", 
                         . == "AG" ~ "0103", 
                         TRUE ~ .))

#  snp1 snp2 snp3
#1 0101 0101 <NA>
#2 0103   AT   GG
#3 0101 0103   GG
#4 0101 0101   GC
```

It checks the condition and replaces with the corresponding value if the condition is `TRUE`. We can add more conditions if needed and with `TRUE ~ .` we keep the values as it is if none of the condition is matched. If we want to change them to `NA` instead we can remove the last line.

```
foo %>%
  mutate_all(~case_when(. == "AA" ~ "0101", 
                        . == "AC" ~ "0102", 
                        . == "AG" ~ "0103"))

#  snp1 snp2 snp3
#1 0101 0101 <NA>
#2 0103 <NA> <NA>
#3 0101 0103 <NA>
#4 0101 0101 <NA>
```

This will change the values to `NA` if none of the above condition is satisfied.

---

Another option using only base R is to create a `lookup` dataframe with old and new values, `unlist` the dataframe, `match` them with old values, get the corresponding new values and replace.

```
lookup <- data.frame(old_val = c("AA", "AC", "AG"), 
                     new_val = c("0101", "0102", "0103"))

foo[] <- lookup$new_val[match(unlist(foo), lookup$old_val)]
```

Comment: This works when the dictionary is short, and you need only to use the dictionary a few times. Otherwise, this would be tedious and make your code unnecessarily long.

Answer (score 7):

Here's something simple that will do the job:

```
key <- c('AA','AC','AG')
val <- c('0101','0102','0103')

lapply(1:3,FUN = function(i){foo[foo == key[i]] <<- val[i]})
foo

 snp1 snp2 snp3
1 0101 0101 <NA>
2 0103   AT   GG
3 0101 0103   GG
4 0101 0101   GC
```

`lapply` will output a list in this case that we don't actually care about. You could assign the result to something if you like and then just discard it. I'm iterating over the indices here, but you could just as easily place the key/vals in a list themselves and iterate over them directly. Note the use of global assignment with `<<-`.

I tinkered with a way to do this with `mapply` but my first attempt didn't work, so I switched. I suspect a solution with `mapply` is possible, though.

Comment: i wouldn't advise the use of the global assignment operator `<<-`.

Comment: @Ramnath Agreed, `<<-` can be risky, but it's not inherently bad.

Comment: This is the only answer that could handle the variant where the original had keys of 0:2 and the task was to convert to equivalent character values. The highest voted answer failed because 0 is not an acceptable index. Ramnaths's and c.gutierrez' answers also failed in my hands. (I didn't test all the answers.) This is the link to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49504035/how-to-substitute-numeric-value-with-character-across-all-columns-of-a-dataframe

Answer (score 6):

Using *dplyr::recode*:

```
library(dplyr)

mutate_all(foo, funs(recode(., "AA" = "0101", "AC" = "0102", "AG" = "0103",
                            .default = NA_character_)))

#   snp1 snp2 snp3
# 1 0101 0101 <NA>
# 2 0103 <NA> <NA>
# 3 0101 0103 <NA>
# 4 0101 0101 <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

Used @Ramnath's answer above, but made it read (what to be replaced and what to be replaced with) from a file and use gsub rather than replace.

```
hrw <- read.csv("hgWords.txt", header=T, stringsAsFactor=FALSE, encoding="UTF-8", sep="\t") 

for (i in nrow(hrw)) 
{
document <- gsub(hrw$from[i], hrw$to[i], document, ignore.case=TRUE)
}
```

hgword.txt contains the following tab separated

```
"from"  "to"
"AA"    "0101"
"AC"    "0102"
"AG"    "0103"
```

Comment: Looks like the best option for me, but I cannot make it work some reason. Output makes little sense.

Answer (score 1):

The poster has a large data frame containing 0, 1, and 2, and wants to change them to AA, AB, and BB respectively.

Use `plyr`:

```
> df <- data.frame(matrix(sample(c(NA, c("0","1","2")), 100, replace = TRUE), 10))
> df
     X1   X2   X3 X4   X5   X6   X7   X8   X9  X10
1     1    2 <NA>  2    1    2    0    2    0    2
2     0    2    1  1    2    1    1    0    0    1
3     1    0    2  2    1    0 <NA>    0    1 <NA>
4     1    2 <NA>  2    2    2    1    1    0    1
... to 10th row

> df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)
```

Create a function over the data frame using `revalue` to replace multiple terms:

```
> library(plyr)
> apply(df, 2, function(x) {x <- revalue(x, c("0"="AA","1"="AB","2"="BB")); x})
      X1   X2   X3   X4   X5   X6   X7   X8   X9   X10 
 [1,] "AB" "BB" NA   "BB" "AB" "BB" "AA" "BB" "AA" "BB"
 [2,] "AA" "BB" "AB" "AB" "BB" "AB" "AB" "AA" "AA" "AB"
 [3,] "AB" "AA" "BB" "BB" "AB" "AA" NA   "AA" "AB" NA  
 [4,] "AB" "BB" NA   "BB" "BB" "BB" "AB" "AB" "AA" "AB"
... and so on
```

Comment: It looks like your input is a data.frame and your output is a matrix. I guess you could coerce back at the end, though.

Answer (score 1):

Not overly original, but should provide an intuitive interface to accomplish replacing multiple values in Base R:

```
# Function performing a mapping replacement:
# replaceMultipleValues => function() 
replaceMultipleValues <- function(df, mapFrom, mapTo){
  # Extract the values in the data.frame: 
  # dfVals => named character vector
  dfVals <- unlist(df)
  
  # Get all values in the mapping & data 
  # and assign a name to them: tmp1 => named character vector 
  tmp1 <- c(
    setNames(mapTo, mapFrom), 
    setNames(dfVals, dfVals)
  )
  
  # Extract the unique values: 
  # valueMap => named character vector
  valueMap <- tmp1[!(duplicated(names(tmp1)))]
  
  # Recode the values in data.frame: res => data.frame
  res <- data.frame(
      matrix(
        valueMap[dfVals], 
        nrow = nrow(df),
        ncol = ncol(df),
        dimnames = dimnames(df)
    )
  )
  
  # Explicitly define the returned object: data.frame => env
  return(res)
}

# Recode values in data.frame: 
# res => data.frame
res <- replaceMultipleValues(
  foo, 
  c("AA", "AC", "AG"), 
  c("0101", "0102", "0103")
)

# Print data.frame to console: 
# data.frame => stdout(console)
res
```

Data:

```
# Import data: foo => data.frame
foo <- data.frame(snp1 = c("AA", "AG", "AA", "AA"), snp2 = c("AA", "AT", "AG", "AA"), snp3 = c(NA, "GG", "GG", "GC"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the old and the new strings are available as columns `old` and `new` of the DataFrame `lookup` then the following still works although `dplyr`'s `recode()` has reached superseded status:

```
library(dplyr)
new_named_with_old <- setNames(lookup[["new"]], lookup[["old"]])
df <- df %>% mutate(across(where(is.character), \(x) recode(x, !!!new_named_with_old)))
```

Note that `recode()` without a specific `.default` supplied will clear all values which are not of the same type as the replacements. Therefore, only columns of type `character` can be mutated this way.