# Odd behaviour when replacing multiple values in R dataframe column using setNames

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I want to replace multiple values in an `R` dataframe using `setNames` as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7548031/4169924, but it gives (seemingly) unexpected results:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Measure = c("Min", "min", "Minimum"), Value = c(1,2,3))
map1 = setNames(c("Minimum", "Minimum", "Minimum"), c("Min", "min", "Minimum"))
df1$Measure <- map1[df1$Measure]
df1
```

Gives the expected result:

```
  Measure Value
1 Minimum 1
2 Minimum 2
3 Minimum 3
```

However, for

```
df2 <- data.frame(Measure = c("Min", "min", "Minimum", "MaxVal"), Value = c(1,2,3,4))
map2 = setNames(c("Minimum", "Minimum", "Minimum", "MaxVal"), c("Min", "min", "Minimum", "MaxVal"))
df2$Measure <- map2[df2$Measure]
df2
```

I get:

```
  Measure Value
1 Minimum 1
2 Minimum 2
3 MaxVal  3
4 Minimum 4
```

Where Measure for rows 3 and 4 seems to be incorrectly replaced. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the first column is a factor, not a character vector. Create it with:

```
df2 <- data.frame(Measure = c("Min", "min", "Minimum", "MaxVal"), Value = c(1,2,3,4), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Or convert at this step:

```
df2$Measure <- map2[as.character(df2$Measure)]
```

Comment: Thanks @mpjdem, so `setNames` can only be used to replace character vectors, but not factors, in which case it behaves unpredictably...

Comment: It is not unpredictable if you look at what's inside the factor, with `as.integer(df2$Measure)`. R uses the factor levels as numerical indices into the map, instead of matching them to the names. And the order of the factor levels is simply alphabetical.