# how to replace multiple values in a specific row in a data.frame?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame, df,

```
df=data.frame(col1=1:5, col2=c("human","worm","worm","yeast","human"))
```

in which column "col2", has strings such as "yeast", "human","worm" and I want to replace these with "sce", "hsa", "cel". How can I do this?

I could do

```
 df[,idx]=lapply(df[,idx],function(x){ gsub(oldname,newname,x) })
```

but this solution only works one at a time but I am seeking to do it all in one go, like a translate table like so

```
 df[,idx]=lapply(df[,idx],function(x){ gsub(c(oldname1,oldname2), c(newname1,newname2),x) })
```

Thanks

Comment: Please include sample data

Comment: this might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547597/dictionary-style-replace-multiple-items

Comment: @Stedy Thank you. That was exactly what I was looking for:

Answer (score 3):

```
df=data.frame(col1=1:5, col2=c("human","worm","worm","yeast","human"))
a=c(yeast="sce",human="hsa",worm="cel")
df$col2 = a[df$col2]
```

Result:

```
> df
  col1 col2
1    1  sce
2    2  hsa
3    3  hsa
4    4  cel
5    5  sce
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using factors.

```
df=data.frame(col1=1:5, col2=c("human","worm","worm","yeast","human"))
    > df
      col1  col2
    1    1 human
    2    2  worm
    3    3  worm
    4    4 yeast
    5    5 human

    > df$col2 = as.character(factor(x = df$col2, levels = c('yeast', 'human', 'worm'), labels = c('sce', 'hsa', 'cel')))
    > df
      col1 col2
    1    1  hsa
    2    2  cel
    3    3  cel
    4    4  sce
    5    5  hsa
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `match`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(col2 = a[match(col2, names(a))])
```