# How to recode multiple values in vector into one value?

Tags: r, replace, recode

I have a problem where my `data.frame` consist of different attributes due to different data source. For example, the `state` column is actually of the same states but in different representation. Note that my actual data is not using US states.

```
    df <- data.frame(Names=c("Adam", "Mark", "Dahlia", "Jeff", "Derek", 
                             "Arnold", "Sheppard", "Dwayne", "Nichols", "Shane"), 
                     Age=c(27, 28, 29, 37, 26, 22, 29, 34, 31, 30), 
                     States=c("AL", "Alaska", "Alabama", "WI", 
                              "Wisconsin", "AZ", "Arizona", "AL", "WI", "AK"))
```

I am trying to recode values like AL, WI, AZ, and AK as Alabama, Wisconsin, Arizona, and Alaska respectively.

So far I came across:

```
    case_when(

        df$States == "AL" ~ "Alabama",
        df$States == "AK" ~ "Alaska",
        df$States == "WI" ~ "Wisconsin",
        df$States == "AZ" ~ "Arizona",
    )
```

and it gives me output:

```
     [1] "Alabama"   NA          NA          "Wisconsin" NA    "Arizona" NA         
     [8] "Alabama"   "Wisconsin" "Alaska"
```

I don't want the `NA` value so what I did is:

```
    case_when(

      df$States == "AL" ~ "Alabama",
      df$States == "Alabama" ~ "Alabama",
      df$States == "AK" ~ "Alaska",
      df$States == "Alaska" ~ "Alaska",
      df$States == "WI" ~ "Wisconsin",
      df$States == "Wisconsin" ~ "Wisconsin",
      df$States == "AZ" ~ "Arizona",
      df$States == "Arizona" ~ "Arizona",

    )
```

It gives me the output I want but I think there is much more simpler way to do this.

I'm thinking about loop because later I would like to turn it into pseudo-code. However, I'm running out of ideas on how to execute this. Really  appreciate everyone helps out here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use dplyr's `recode` function together with a named vector. I use `setNames` to create a named character vector (something like a key-value pair), but you can make your vector out of whatever data you have. Using your example, we can set up some keys and values:

```r
keys <- state.abb # the abbreviations you want to replace
vals <- state.name # the replacement values
keysvals <- setNames(vals, keys) # create named vector
```

Now call `recode`. Make sure you use the `!!!` to unquote and splice:

```r
library(dplyr)

df$States <- recode(df$States, !!!keysvals)
```

Which will return:

```r
      Names Age    States
1      Adam  27   Alabama
2      Mark  28    Alaska
3    Dahlia  29   Alabama
4      Jeff  37 Wisconsin
5     Derek  26 Wisconsin
6    Arnold  22   Arizona
7  Sheppard  29   Arizona
8    Dwayne  34   Alabama
9   Nichols  31 Wisconsin
10    Shane  30    Alaska
```

Comment: Thanks @gersht. This really helps. My other question, is the `keys` and `vals` have to be in the same length? Because, my data is that I would like to change let say for example `MY` or `Malaysian` into `Malaysia` and `SG` and `Singaporean` into `Singapore`. My concern is that, sometimes there are multiple attributes in `keys` that using different abbreviation but I want to change it into one same names.

Comment: @mojek they do have to be the same length, but given your example that shouldn't be a problem. All you have to do is add multiple key-value pairs for each possible key, where the value is simply duplicated. For example you can do `keysvals <- c(MY=Malaysia, Malaysian=Malaysia, SG = Singapore, Singaporean = Singapore)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to match with US state names we can use the inbuilt vector `state.abb` and `state.name` to match and replace.

```
inds <- match(df$States, state.abb)
df$States[which(!is.na(inds))] <- state.name[na.omit(inds)]

df
#       Names Age   States
#1      Adam  27   Alabama
#2      Mark  28    Alaska
#3    Dahlia  29   Alabama
#4      Jeff  37 Wisconsin
#5     Derek  26 Wisconsin
#6    Arnold  22   Arizona
#7  Sheppard  29   Arizona
#8    Dwayne  34   Alabama
#9   Nichols  31 Wisconsin
#10    Shane  30    Alaska
```

Also you can reduce the length of `case_when` by using `%in%` which can compare multiple vectors instead of only one using `==`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(States = case_when(States %in% c("AL", "Alabama") ~ "Alabama", 
                            States %in% c("AK", "Alaska")~ "Alaska", 
                            States %in% c("WI", "Wisconsin")~ "Wisconsin", 
                            States %in% c("AZ", "Arizona")~ "Arizona", 
                             TRUE ~ NA_character_))
```

Comment: Thank you. But my data actually not using US states.

Comment: @mojek ok..in that case you can then use the `case_when` answer. Also this is quite similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547597/dictionary-style-replace-multiple-items see if you could use any of the answer from there.