# Vectorizing multiple if statements in a function

Tags: r, function, if-statement, vectorization

I'm trying to create a function that receives a word and returns a number based in which group that word belongs to, I've created the following function, which only works with single inputs:

```
get_humor <- function(x) {

  feeling <- str_to_lower(x)

  if (x %in% group5) return(5)
  if (x %in% group4) return(4)
  if (x %in% group3) return(3)
  if (x %in% group2) return(2)
  if (x %in% group1) return(1)


}
```

I know that I can use nested ifelses, like this:

```
ifelse(x %in% nv5, 5, 
         ifelse(x %in% nv4, 4,
                ifelse(x %in% nv3, 3,
                       ifelse(x %in% nv2, 2, 1))))
```

But there is a way to make a vectorized version of this function without using other auxiliary functions, like `lapply()` or `Vectorize()`?

Comment: `sapply(word_list, FUN = function(x) ifelse(x %in% nv5, 5, 
         ifelse(x %in% nv4, 4,
                ifelse(x %in% nv3, 3,
                       ifelse(x %in% nv2, 2, 1)))))` should do the trick. `ifelse` _is_ vectorized, but you're probably running into issues with logical recycling, if you compare a vector `x` to another with `%in%`

Comment: Maybe `dplyr::case_when()`

Comment: In order to vectorize, you should use a list of groups:`groups <- list(group1, group2, ..., group5)`

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. I think you could vectorize this with a single `match` statement

Comment: Suggested duplicate: [dictionary-style replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7547597/903061)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option. The key is to store your groups in a list over which you can loop/apply/map.

```
groups <- list(group1, group2, group3, group4, group5)

# Using apply
get_humor <- function(x, groups) {
  x_in <- sapply(groups, function(g) x %in% g)
  max(which(x_in))
}

# Using purrr
get_humor <- function(x, groups) {
  x_in <- purrr::map_lgl(groups, function(g) x %in% g)
  max(which(x_in))
}
```

This checks which groups `x` belongs to and returns the highest group index.

Another option is to return as soon as a group is found. This can be done with a `for` loop but also with `detect_index` from `purrr` which does just that in a one-liner.

```
purrr::detect_index(groups, ~ x %in% ., .dir = "backwards")
```

Note by default `detect_index` will return the *first* index at which the predicate is true. Since you want the *last* index, you need to specify `.dir = "backwards"`.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the examples where a for loop actually makes sense in `R`, because you don't want a list of all possible return values and if you found the right one you don't need the other ones. So, how 'bout this:

```
get_humor <- function(x, groupList)
    for (i in seq_along(groupList)){
        if (x %in% groupList[[i]]) return(i)
    }
}
```