# In R, how will I replace set of values with another set

Tags: r

I would like to replace only a part of a set in R.

Specifically I need to replace the values of a column variable; Let say `ds` has `col1` which takes values like `A, B, C, D, E` which I want to replace with some different values like `1,15, L1100, PQ7, 243` (some random distinct things).

For example, I want to replace few values not all eg. replace only `A, B, C` by `'1','15', 'L1100'` and `D, E` will remain as it is. Most importantly, I don't want to merge to get this done. I want without merging solution like in python replace function which is very elegant.

```
ds['col1'].replace(['A','B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],['1','15', 'L1100', 'PQ7', '243'],inplace=True)
```

Comment: Can you share a reproducible example using dput() ?

Comment: You can try using `recode` or `case_when` in `dplyr`. See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547597/dictionary-style-replace-multiple-items

Comment: There are even more possibilities this problem can be approached using dplyr. You could use mutate() with recode() or mutate() with ifelse().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small example showing how to randomly `replace` the first 3 values in `v1`

```
> v1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")

> v2 <- c(1, 15, "L1100", "PQ7", 243)

> replace(v1, 1:3, sample(v2, 3))
[1] "L1100" "15"    "1"     "D"     "E"
```

---

**Update**

```
v1 <- c("A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "E", "C", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "D", "E")

v2 <- c(1, 15, "L1100")

replace(
  v1,
  v1 %in% c("A", "B", "C"),
  v2[na.omit(match(v1, c("A", "B", "C")))]
)
```

gives

```
 [1] "1"     "15"    "1"     "15"    "L1100" "D"     "1"     "15"    "L1100"
[10] "D"     "E"     "E"     "L1100" "1"     "15"    "L1100" "D"     "E"
[19] "D"     "E"
```

Comment: Your solution does not work since v1 is a very long list/ a column of a dataset.

Comment: @Tamal What do you mean `does not work`? Any error? I don't think the length of long list fails the code.

Comment: It does not give any error but it does not give the right result. List is like this: ("A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "D","A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "E","C","A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "D", "E"........ so on). I want to replace all A, B and C by   '1','15', 'L1100'. Please understand position of A, B, C are fixed but length of list is 100,000.

Comment: This works fine. Thank you @ThomasIsCoding