# Are there alternative r base functions to pivot_wider?

Tags: r, pivot

I have the follow type of table:

| SEZ | Class | Val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1_1_1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1_1_1 | 5 | 2 |
| 1_1_2 | 5 | 2 |
| 1_1_3 | 1 | 1 |
| 1_1_3 | 5 | 2 |
| 1_1_4 | 1 | 1 |
| 1_1_5 | 2 | 1 |
| 1_2_1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1_2_1 | 5 | 2 |

In order to spread column "Class" in multiple new columns getting value from "Val" column I used pivot_wider and everything gone well. I entered this code:

`pivot_wider(names_from = Class, values_from = Val, names_sort=T, values_fill = list(n = 0))`

obataining a result like this:

| Sez | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1_1_1 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 1_1_2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 1_1_3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |

Unfortunately I have to use an external computer where only the basic R packages are present, and the times for requesting additional packages are not short.

I tried to use this solution:

`newdata <- xtabs(dat$Val ~ dat$Sez + dat$Class)`

But it gives me a frequency distribution with each row:

| SEZ | Class | Freq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1_1_1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1_1_2 | 1 | 0 |
| 1_1_3 | 1 | 1 |
| 1_1_4 | 1 | 1 |
| 1_1_5 | 1 | 0 |
| 1_2_1 | 1 | 1 |

I'm looking for a solution with the basic function of R that gives me an object equal to the one got using with pivot_wider.

Comment: It took me few hours more, to work around it, when the column `Values` contain strings instead of integers. But I posted my solution below, in case somebody had the same issue when running the nice answer from @akrun. It is basically about indexing and remapping (couple more of lines)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We create the 'Class' as `factor` and use `xtabs`

```
df1$Class <- factor(df1$Class, levels = 1:7)

 xtabs(Val ~ SEZ + Class, df1)
```

-output

```
      Class
SEZ     1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  1_1_1 2 0 0 0 2 0 0
  1_1_2 0 0 0 0 2 0 0
  1_1_3 1 0 0 0 2 0 0
  1_1_4 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
  1_1_5 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  1_2_1 2 0 0 0 2 0 0
```

If we need a `data.frame` output

```
out <- as.data.frame.matrix( xtabs(Val ~ SEZ + Class, df1))
out$SEZ <- row.names(out)
row.names(out) <- NULL
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(SEZ = c("1_1_1", "1_1_1", "1_1_2", "1_1_3", "1_1_3", 
"1_1_4", "1_1_5", "1_2_1", "1_2_1"), Class = c(1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L), Val = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your reply. Your solution is very good, however when I try to create a new variable:  new_variable <- xtabs(Val ~ SEZ + Class, df1)                                                                                              
the result is an object with three columns "Sez", "Class" and "Freq", while I would like to get an object with Class mode in column  like 1,2,3, etc; in row "SEZ" and in the cells the values of "Val". I don't know if I'm wrong to do something!

Comment: @Antonio do you need the ouptu as in the update

Comment: Akrun your solution is what I was trying to get from data, it works well! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option using `reshape` + `merge`

```
reshape(
  merge(df,
    expand.grid(
      SEZ = unique(df$SEZ),
      Class = 1:7
    ),
    all = TRUE
  ),
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "SEZ",
  timevar = "Class"
)
```

gives

```
     SEZ Val.1 Val.2 Val.3 Val.4 Val.5 Val.6 Val.7
1  1_1_1     2    NA    NA    NA     2    NA    NA
8  1_1_2    NA    NA    NA    NA     2    NA    NA
15 1_1_3     1    NA    NA    NA     2    NA    NA
22 1_1_4     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
29 1_1_5    NA     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
36 1_2_1     2    NA    NA    NA     2    NA    NA
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, thank you for your answer and solution!

Answer (score 0):

What happens when "Values" column contains integers?

I tried to apply the @akran solution (posted above) to this table (that by chance had strings instead of integers in the column "Values"

### Data

```
"1_1_4", "1_1_5", "1_2_1", "1_2_1"), Class = c(1L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 
5L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 5L), Val = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Running this will cause error:

```
xtabs(Val ~ SEZ + Class, df1)
```

[image]

We need to convert the Output column "Val" into numeric, and later return it back to their text.
This script do the work (**R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)** & **dplyr 1.1.2**):

```
# create list to translate
list_mapTclass <- seq(1:length(unique(df1$Val)))
print(length(list_mapTclass))
names(list_mapTclass) <-unique(df1$Val)

list_mapTclass[1:3]

df1$idxVal <- sapply(df1$Val, function(x) list_mapTclass[[x]] )

#essential! conver to factor
#df1$idxVal <- factor(df1$idxVal)

#df1

#xtabs(idxVal ~ SEZ + Class, df1)
wide_df_matrix <-xtabs(idxVal ~ SEZ + Class, df1)
 



#print(list_mapTclassInverted[1:3])
#--- add subid
wide_df0 <- as.data.frame.matrix( wide_df_matrix) %>% 
  setNames(paste0('col_', names(.))) #%>%

wide_df0
# reconvert values into the therapyclass content

# inverted list:

list_mapTclassInverted <- setNames(names(list_mapTclass), list_mapTclass)
# sometimes if you dont have 0s , you have to include it in the "list_mapTclassInverted" , as "Unknown"
#list_mapTclassInverted[['0']] <- 'Unknown'
print(list_mapTclassInverted)
wide_df0



# Next piece of code is to go through the full table and convert all the integers into their text
### VERY USEFUL! (Thanks to: @Martin Morgan - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7547597/dictionary-style-replace-multiple-items )

wide_df00 <- wide_df0
wide_df00[] <- list_mapTclassInverted[unlist(wide_df00)]

wide_df00
## convert to a dataframe

wide_df0$SEZ <- row.names(wide_df0) 
row.names(wide_df0) <- NULL

# See the output
wide_df0
```

Result:

[image]

I will write another post ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77448239/alternative-to-pivot-wider-in-r-base-and-a-bit-of-dplyr)) with this issue in case this one does not match fully with the question.
Hope this helps!
Sometimes is time consuming to do things in R base, but as mentioned in the question, when you have to use no updated technology and you are not the IT admin there is no other way (specially if you have to deliver by tomorrow!).