# Using R and ggplot2 is there a better way to visualize TRUE and FALSE Boolean Value columns?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boolean, visualization, boolean-logic

So I've got a larger data set, but for simplicity's sake I've done my best to offer a simplified version of my problem/dataset:

So there are a total of 3 Little Pigs. One of the pigs owns just one house I want to plot on the Y axis the total home values and then a faceted view of how much each pig owns.

| HOUSES | HOUSEVALUE | PIG1 | PIG2 | PIG3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hay | 30000 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE |
| Sticks | 70000 | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE |
| Bricks | 100000 | TRUE | TRUE | TRUE |

And here's a quick sketch of what I'd like this to look like:
[image]

I'm very rusty with my R usage as well as my GGPLOT2 usage. I'm doing all kinds of crazy stuff with this data, such as:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)
piggies <- read_csv("piggies.csv")
ggplot(piggies, aes(x=PIG1, fill=as.factor(HOUSEVALUE)))+geom_bar(position='dodge')
ggplot(piggies, aes(x=PIG2, fill=as.factor(HOUSEVALUE)))+geom_bar(position='dodge')
```

[image]

[image]

I understand the above ggplot2 visualizations are borderline insane, but I'm having the hardest time tracking down solid resources for columns that are boolean values and making the Y axis represent something other than "Count"

(Edited the example GGPlot formulae to be slightly less insane than my original example)

Comment: Try `df1 %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('PIG')) %>% filter(value) %>% ggplot(aes(x = name, y = HOUSEVALUE, fill = HOUSES)) + geom_col() + facet_wrap(~ HOUSES)`  Or could be `df1 %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('PIG')) %>% mutate(value = factor(value)) %>% ggplot(aes(x = name, y = HOUSEVALUE, fill = value)) + geom_col() + facet_wrap(~ HOUSES)`

Comment: Well, your hand sketch has house value on the y-axis, and your current plot has house value on the y axis, so that would be a good place to start.  Also, ggplot, as part of the tidyverse, is designed to work with [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) data.  Your data set is not tidy because you have information (the pig names) in your column names.  Make your data tidy, you won't need any Booleans, and your life will become much simpler.  You might also investigate the difference between `geom_histogram` and `geom_bar`.

Comment: Limey - fair point, I didn't think I was anywhere close and figured I'd edit that sample, just wanted to put something up... but I appreciate the link, I'm going to look at how I might optimize my CSV file.

Comment: Akrun, I tried that but received `Error in df1 %>% pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("PIG")) %>% filter(value) %>%  : 
  could not find function "%>%"`

Comment: @Limey How would you make this particular data tidy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, it would give the total amount each pig owns of each type stacked. Similar to what @Akrun said, it uses pivot_longer before plotting:

```
dat<-data.frame("HOUSES" = c("Hay", "Sticks", "Bricks"), "HOUSEVALUE" = c(30000, 70000, 100000), "PIG1" = c(T,T,T), "PIG2" = c(F,T,T), "PIG3" = c(F,F,T))


library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

dat%>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("PIG"))%>%
  filter(value)%>%
  ggplot()+
  aes(name, HOUSEVALUE, fill = HOUSES)+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Comment: This worked for me and I really appreciate it. However, is there a way to do it like this: `pivot_longer(cols = PIG1, PIG2)%>%` - This gives me an error, but some bigger data I plan to use this approach with the names are all different.

Comment: The way I would do something where I need multiple names is to use ```grep```, so replace the ```pivot_longer``` with this line, where you can just separate names with a | ```pivot_longer(cols = grep("PIG1|PIG2|PIG3", names(.)))```

Comment: While this works great for my initial visual, is there a way to do this without using the pivot_longer method? Even if it would require changing how the data is laid out?

Comment: If you are looking for an alternative to ```pivot_longer```, then there are other options (These are ```pivot_wider```, but I think it demonstrates my point): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67778341/are-there-alternative-r-base-functions-to-pivot-wider

Comment: If you are trying to avoid reshaping the data, then I'm less sure of how you could do that.  The best I can think of is something like ```dat%>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_bar(aes(x = "PIG1", y = HOUSEVALUE[PIG1], fill = HOUSES), stat = "identity")+
  geom_bar(aes(x = "PIG2", y = c(0,HOUSEVALUE[PIG2]), fill = HOUSES), stat = "identity")+
  geom_bar(aes(x = "PIG3", y = c(0,0,HOUSEVALUE[PIG3]), fill = HOUSES), stat = "identity")```. But this isn't automated, so you'd have to figure out how to put in those 0s.