# Create new column in the data frame which label rows based on their category variable

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data set called one_plot, the head of which can be seen below. I am trying to add a column to label rows based on their `subCategory_id` using the dplyr package.

For example `subCategory_id %in% c(1:4)` to be labeled as `"Premium"`, `subCategory_id %in% c(4:12)` to be labeled `"Base"` and `subCategory_id %in% c(12:20)` to be labeled `"Other"`.

Data looks like this:

```
product_id product_origin product_price subCategory_id    GBP
          1      Australia    0.36154597              1 371.31
          2            USA    0.14425684              1 148.15
          3            USA    0.09020571              1  92.64
          5            USA    0.35793051              1 367.59
          6            USA    0.19523482              1 200.51
```

I tried using the command

```
one_plot$cat_type <- filter(one_plot, subCategory_id %in% c(1:4) = "Premium")
```

Comment: check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658316/create-new-column-based-on-4-values-in-another-column

Comment: This is a good place to use `cut`. Something like `df$newVar <-  cut(df$subCategory_id, breaks=c(-Inf, 4, 12), labels=c("Prem", "base")`.

Comment: I haven't tested the code since you haven't provided us with reproducible code; use `dput` for providing sample data set. Also read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
df <- data.frame(id=1:12, otherStuff = letters[1:12])

df %>% 
    mutate(Label = lapply(id, function(x) {
        if (x %in% c(1:4)) {
            'Premium'
        } else if (x %in% c(5:10)) {
            'Base'
        } else if (x %in% c(11:12)) {
            'other'
        }
    }))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! Do you mind explaining what is meand by the otherStuff??

Comment: It is simply second column.