# Grouping the data into categories based on a column

Tags: bash, text, awk

I have a tab delimited file which have 2 columns as:

```
new.txt
    1.01   yes
    2.00   no
    0.93   no
    1.2223 yes
    1.7211 no
```

I want to modify the contents of it as if there are two categories as:

```
new_categorized.txt
yes    no
1.01   2.00
1.2223 0.93
       1.7211
```

I have found a similar question with an answer in R ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658316/create-new-column-based-on-4-values-in-another-column)) ,however I need to do it with bash or awk..
I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
!($2 in label2colNr) {
    label2colNr[$2] = ++numCols
    colNr2label[numCols] = $2
}
{
    colNr = label2colNr[$2]
    val[++numRows[colNr],colNr] = $1
    maxRows = (numRows[colNr] > maxRows ? numRows[colNr] : maxRows)
}
END {
    for (colNr=1; colNr <= numCols; colNr++) {
        printf "%s%s", colNr2label[colNr], (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
    }

    for (rowNr=1; rowNr <= maxRows; rowNr++) {
        for (colNr=1; colNr <= numCols; colNr++) {
            printf "%s%s", val[rowNr,colNr], (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
yes     no
1.01    2.00
1.2223  0.93
        1.7211
```

The above will work with any awk in any shell on any UNIX system no matter how many categories you have in the 2nd field and no matter what their values are.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried but, it gave me the exact new.txt instead of categories..

Comment: That's simply impossible. You must've copy/pasted wrong.

Comment: Sorry. You are right, I had a typo. Your answer works

Comment: @EdMorton: I recycled your code right there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48253326/3776858

Comment: @Cyrus Glad to hear it. It should really be a FAQ :-) .

Answer (score 2):

With bash, GNU grep and paste:

```
echo -e "yes\tno"
paste <(grep -Po '^\t\K.*(?=\tyes)' new.txt) <(grep -Po '^\t\K.*(?=\tno)' new.txt)
```

Output:

```
yes     no
1.01    2.00
1.2223  0.93
        1.7211
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In here, how did you direct the output to another file?

Comment: `{ echo ...; paste ... ; } > file.txt`. Last `;` is important.

Answer (score 2):

GNU **`awk`** solution:

```
awk '{ a[$2][($2=="yes"? ++y : ++n)]=$1 }
     END{ 
         max=(y > n? y:n); 
         print "yes","no";
         for(i=1; i<=max; i++) print a["yes"][i], a["no"][i] 
     }' OFS='\t' file | column -tn
```

The output:

```
yes     no
1.01    2.00
1.2223  0.93
        1.7211
```

Comment: Thank you but it complained as : awk: line 1: syntax error at or near [
awk: line 5: syntax error at or near [

Comment: @bapors, 1) check your awk version; 2) check your code for errors. Here's a screenshot https://ibb.co/c5AEwm