# Adding a new flag column based on another column

Tags: r

I am new to R and I am trying to create a third column, of flagged data based on the ID column. Flagging is supposed to be for 0 for Secret identity and 1 for anything else. My table currently looks like this (as an example, not the full table);

```
    name             ID               
 1. Spider-man       Secret Identity 
 2. Captain America  Public Identity 
 3. Wolverine        Public Identity  
 4. Iron Man         Public Identity  
 5. Thor             No Dual Identity 
 6. Otto Octavius    Secret Identity
 7. Reed Richards    Public Identity
```

I have had no luck in coding this third column of flagging based on the ID column, listing either '0' or '1' depending on the ID field. Like this;

```
    name             ID               Flag
 1. Spider-man       Secret Identity  0
 2. Captain America  Public Identity  1 
 3. Wolverine        Public Identity  1
 4. Iron Man         Public Identity  1
 5. Thor             No Dual Identity 1
 6. Otto Octavius    Secret Identity  0
 7. Reed Richards    Public Identity  1
```

Comment: try using `ifelse()`. you can do something like `df |> mutate(Flag = ifelse(ID == "Secret Identity", 0, 1))`

Comment: or `df$Flag <- ifelse(df$ID == "Secret Identity", 0, 1)`

Comment: my code says can't find the function "mutate"

Comment: Or `within(df, Flag <- as.numeric(ID != "Secret Identity"))` - just ensure you change `df` to whatever your data frame is called.

Comment: @Benjamin Kinnie install the dplyr package `install.packages("dplyr"); library(dplyr)`

Comment: All of these suggestions work for getting the flag variable for the ID, however this one;  "df$Flag <- ifelse(df$ID == "Secret Identity", 0, 1)" worked exactly as I needed it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create new column based on 4 values in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658316/create-new-column-based-on-4-values-in-another-column)